# in Gerrit, amend commit pushed by other author

Tags: git, gerrit

If I have the change ID of the commit. Can I amend a commit pushed by another author? If so, what do I need to do?

Like so?

```
git commit --amend --no-verify -m '<message> Change-Id: <change-id>'
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: Note that "change ID" is a *Gerrit* concept, not a Git concept. The goal of a *change ID* is to track a change regardless of underlying Git commit *hash IDs*. When you use `git commit --amend`, you're not *modifying* a Git commit at all, you're telling Git: *use this new commit instead of the old one*. The old commit will continue to exist on the Gerrit system until the `git push --force`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/[CD]/[EFG]/[HI] && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
... do the fixes ...
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: Indeed. The "Commiter" row would change instead. Note that when you need to do so, you may use "`--reset-author`", which both Author and Commiter fields to your own identity and current date.

Alternatively, when importing something coming from another person (for instance, when manually applying a patch then committing the changes), you can use "`--author="FirstName LastName <email@somewhere.world>`" to explicitly set the author.

Comment: `git push --force`